# xmodmap stopped working in the latest Google Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, xmodmap

I remap <kbd>Insert</kbd>,<kbd>Home</kbd>,<kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, and it have worked for many years, but with the latest Google Chrome update, it ignores the remapping, and preforms the action if it where were no remapping. Outside of Chrome the remapping works.

Any idea how to get Chrome to honor the remapped keys?

Answer (score 1):

I do similar key remappings and have had the same problem. I'm not sure that xmodmap remappings ever really worked properly in Chrome. For example, in Google Sheets, pressing the modifier key (caps lock in my case) would clear the current cell.

I've solved the problem by (a) buying a new USB keyboard that supports QMK firmware and (b) discovering that my System76 laptop makes [customizing the keyboard firmware trivial](https://github.com/system76/ec/blob/master/doc/keyboard-layout-customization.md).

I realise that both those options likely involve new hardware and significant expense, so aren't ideal.

I think the fact that Chrome is able to bypass the remapped keys indicates that the remapping is being done at too high a level. Possibly remapping using evdev might work better, but I haven't tried that. Good luck and sorry I don't have a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your specific problem but I was having similar issues with my mappings not working in Google Sheets.

Basically, as far as I understand it, the capslock key code was still being sent to the browser - which I don't know enough about to understand in the OS - so what I ended up doing was overriding the `keydown` event in Google Sheets specifically. Not ideal, definitely not. However, this works to stop Google Sheets from clearing out the current cell.

You have to install TamperMonkey and add the following script. Make sure the script is run at `document-start`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Sheets Capslock Blocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Take control of Google Sheets.
// @author       nate-wilkins
// @match        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

'use strict';

console.log('Running Google Sheets Capslock Blocker');

const element = document.createElement('div');
const originalAddEventListener = element.__proto__.addEventListener;
element.__proto__.addEventListener = function (event, handler) {
    if (event === 'keydown') {
        originalAddEventListener.call(this, event, function () {
            console.log({ e: arguments[0] });
            if (arguments[0].key === 'ModeChange') {
                console.log(">> Blocked Caps <<");
                return;
            } else {
                handler.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
    } else {
        originalAddEventListener.call(this, event, handler);
    }
};
```

This allows me to have a `.xmodmap` of:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Up
keysym j = j J Down
```

Which lets me navigate Google Sheets with very basic vi/vim movement keys.

So glad this works finally. Let me know if you find a lower level way to fix this though would really appreciate it!